# Flutter web displaying 'Error in firebase' in the appbar

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web, firebase-analytics

Firebase cloud messaging service was working fine with flutter web. When I added firebase analytics, now I get this error. There is no log entry in the console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was an error from the flutter_local_notifications... I resolved this by commenting

```
 // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  //     .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
  //         AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
  //     ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```